# pymongo fetch data inside nested data

Tags: mongodb

Mongodata

```
    [
    {
        "structure": [
        {
            "name": "some folder",
            "values": [
            {
                "report_name": "new report",
                "report_heading": "sjsdjjs",
                "background": "#fff",
                "grid": false,
                "datasource": "newa",
                "unique_report_name": "newreport"
            },
            {
                "report_name": "test vaga test",
                "report_heading": "bar sksk",
                "background": "#fff",
                "grid": false,
                "datasource": "dgr_data",
                "unique_report_name": "testvagatest"
            }
            ],
            "type": 1
        }
        ],
        "unique_report_id": 536862
    }
    ]
```

query

```
query = mycol.find({"structure.values.unique_report_name": "testvagatest"})
res = json.loads(dumps(query))
```

Here is the query i am using to fetch data by filtering unique_report_name inside nested data.
But it is not working.

I am using pymongo client to fetch data

```
    {
        "report_name": "test vaga test",
        "report_heading": "bar sksk",
        "background": "#fff",
        "grid": false,
        "datasource": "dgr_data",
        "unique_report_name": "testvagatest"
    }
```

I am expecting above result.

Please take a look how can to achive this

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "structure.values.unique_report_name": "testvagatest"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$structure"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$structure.values"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "structure.values.unique_report_name": "testvagatest"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$structure.values"
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QhsObpa0fP2)